# Trace of power of Laplacian matrix of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, trace, graph-laplacian

It is well known that, for symmetric matrices, the trace the product of three matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ is the same, independent of the order of $A$, $B$, $C$, that is,

$$\operatorname{tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(ACB) = \operatorname{tr}(BAC) = \operatorname{tr}(BCA) = \operatorname{tr}(CAB) = \operatorname{tr}(CBA)$$

And, that the trace is invariant under circular shifts,

$$\operatorname{tr}(ABCD) = \operatorname{tr}(DABC)$$

but, in general, it is not possible to make any permutation of we consider more than three factors.

I am studying the power of Laplacian matrix $L^m =(D-A)^m$, where $D$ is the degree matrix of a graph and $A$ its adjacency matrix. When opening $(D-A)^m$, I want to relate all factors that has same number of $D$’s and $A$’s together, like when opening $(d-a)^m$ for $a,d\in\mathbb{R}$, which results in $$\sum_{i=0}^m{m\choose j}(-1)^jd^{m-j}a^j.$$

For example, $m=5$, is there any relation of $\operatorname{tr}(ADADA)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(D^2A^3)$? Something  $\operatorname{tr}(ADADA) = \operatorname{tr}(D^2A^3) + o(n^5)$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The equality ${\rm Tr}(ABC)={\rm Tr}(ACB)$ also fails. Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2& 0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad C=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} $$ Then $$ABC=\begin{pmatrix}2& 0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad ACB=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi Ryszard, actually for symmetric matrices it works, because ABC^T = CBA and using the circuit shift property we have all possibilities.

Comment: I have missed the symmetry assumptions. By the way do you assume an arbitary graph or there are some homogeneity assumptions on its structure ?

Comment: In this case, it is an arbitrary graph. I want to understand more of the power of the Laplacian matrix, but it is hard without the matrices commuting inside the trace. When dealing with D^iA^j it is pretty easy to have an understanding of the trace by the properties of A^j.